# How to group a list by name with a newline after each group in shell?

Tags: shell, newline

I have a list that I would like to group by name. This should be done with a newline after each group.
Here is an example file:

```
$ cat file
2015-07-09 07:03:46    7.5 GiB apple-foo.txt.gpg
2015-07-22 11:36:36    6.9 GiB apple-bar.txt.gpg
2015-07-27 04:40:34   31.0 GiB banana-here.txt.gpg
2015-07-07 20:28:17   30.6 GiB banana-even.txt.gpg
2015-07-19 15:02:20   30.8 GiB banana-more.txt.gpg
2015-07-26 00:05:11    1.9 GiB coconut-something.txt.gpg
2015-07-23 03:34:41    2.1 GiB coconut-else.txt.gpg
2015-07-24 03:34:40   12.1 GiB date-yougetit.txt.gpg
```

And this is the output I am trying to get:

```
2015-07-09 07:03:46    7.5 GiB apple-foo.txt.gpg
2015-07-22 11:36:36    6.9 GiB apple-bar.txt.gpg

2015-07-27 04:40:34   31.0 GiB banana-here.txt.gpg
2015-07-07 20:28:17   30.6 GiB banana-even.txt.gpg
2015-07-19 15:02:20   30.8 GiB banana-more.txt.gpg

2015-07-26 00:05:11    1.9 GiB coconut-something.txt.gpg
2015-07-23 03:34:41    2.1 GiB coconut-else.txt.gpg

2015-07-24 03:34:40   12.1 GiB date-yougetit.txt.gpg
```

I manage to extract the unique names (apple, banana, coconut, date) but I am failing to add a new line after the last occurrence of each unique name.
Is anyone able to help me out? awk and sed are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk -F\- 'NR>1&&$1!=last{print ""}{last=$1}1' infile
```

**Explanation**

`-F\-` :Set field separator to `–`.

`NR>1` :Omit first line from checking.

`last=$1` :Always save the last occurrence of the *group key*.

`1` :Print the current line.

`1!=last{print ""}` :If *key* `$1` is **NOT** equal to `last` print the separator.

**Update**

For the current source use:

```
awk 'split($NF,a,"-"){current=a[1]}NR>1&&current!=last{print ""}{last=current}1' infile
```

**Explanation 2**

`split($NF,a,"-"){current=a[1]` :To get the key `a[1]` from the last field of the line `$NF` by splitting it at `-` char.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The awk command worked for the simple example, but I'm afraid it didn't reflect my actual problem. I changed my example now.

Comment: Yeah, this did the job, although the command is now even more complex. Thanks a lot @klashxx!